# Android webview : Show the default JS popup for web page access authentication

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

This is a screenshot from google chrome. When I try to access a page with basic authentication, this authentication dialog is shown. I want this feature be enabled in my android `Webview` as well and let the user enter their username and password. But instead it just shows the `401` unauthorized page without showing this popup. How would I achieve this in the `Webview`? I have tried adding these snippets but still unable to show this popup.

```
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to override [WebViewClient.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to handle the authentication. Your code is responsible for showing the authentication dialog or retrieving saved username/password. This will not be done for you.

This is the code that worked in my app. I remove some parts of it for clarity.

```
    @Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(final WebView view,
                                      final HttpAuthHandler handler,
                                      final String host,
                                      final String realm) {
    if(handler.useHttpAuthUsernamePassword()) {
        String[] creds = view.getHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host,realm);
        if(creds!=null) {
            handler.proceed(creds[0],creds[1]);
            return;
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
// set up the input for user name and password here
// ... removed for clarity ...
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String name = nameEdit.getText().toString();
            String pass = passEdit.getText().toString();
            view.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(host,realm,name,pass);
            handler.proceed(name,pass);
        }
    });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
          handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Any example? Because I tried this method too but gave me 401

Comment: I edited my answer to include some code. It works in my app.